# Calculating distance between two point layers based on matching ID using QGIS

Tags: field-calculator, geometry, distance, getfeatureinfo

I have two point vectors in QGIS. One contains several coordinates, which are grouped geographically by a reference in the field name `PID`.

[image: Coordinates]

I also have a point vector of the centroids from each group of coordinates:

[image: Centroids]

I want to calculate the distance (in degrees is fine) between each of my individual points from my first table to the corresponding centroids in my second table. So for example, for each point in the PID group `PID0001`, I want to calculate the distance to the centroid of `PID0001`. And so on, for all my points, for all the different PID groups.

I am trying to use the Field Calculator to calculate these distances. But my knowledge only goes as far as calculating these values for a specific value within a field.

See code below:

```sql
length(shortest_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature('LandscapeAll', 'PID', 'PID0001'))))
```

This code works but it will obviously give me the distance between all my individual points and the centroid of `PID0001`.

How do I modify my code so it looks up the value from the PID field for each individual point from `table 1`, and then calculates the distance based on the centroid which has the same value in the PID column from `table 2`?

For reference, I have named my first table `PlotAll` and the second one with centroids `LandscapeAll`.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @J.Monticolo:

> Just replace `PID0001` by the `"PID"` field value :
> `length(shortest_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature('LandscapeAll', 'PID', "PID"))))`.